# Print docstring with default --help function

Tags: python, docstring

I have a code that looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''Plot multiple DOS/PDOS in a single plot
run python dplot.py -h for more usage
'''
import argparse
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#  parser.add_argument('--dos', help='Plot the dos', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--dos', nargs='*', help='Files to plot')
parser.add_argument('--label', nargs='*', help='Label of the files')
parser.add_argument('--fermi', help='Fermi Energy')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

If I run this code with `python foo.py -h`, I get the output:

```
usage: foo.py [-h] [--dos [DOS ...]] [--label [LABEL ...]] [--fermi FERMI]

options:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --dos [DOS ...]      Files to plot
  --label [LABEL ...]  Label of the files
  --fermi FERMI        Fermi Energy
```

I know I can separately print the docstring using `print(__doc__)`.

But, I want the `python foo.py -h` to print both the docstring together with the present `-h` output. That is, `python foo.py -h` should give:

```
Plot multiple DOS/PDOS in a single plot
run python dplot.py -h for more usage

usage: foo.py [-h] [--dos [DOS ...]] [--label [LABEL ...]] [--fermi FERMI]
    
    options:
      -h, --help           show this help message and exit
      --dos [DOS ...]      Files to plot
      --label [LABEL ...]  Label of the files
      --fermi FERMI        Fermi Energy
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the local module docstring with `__doc__` If you use that as the  description to `ArgumentParser()` such as:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
```

It will come pretty close to what you want:

```
usage: foo.py [-h] [--dos [DOS ...]] [--label [LABEL ...]] [--fermi FERMI]

Plot multiple DOS/PDOS in a single plot run python dplot.py -h for more usage

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --dos [DOS ...]      Files to plot
  --label [LABEL ...]  Label of the files
  --fermi FERMI        Fermi Energy
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `argparse.ArgumentParser` with more information:

```py
argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='description')
```

So putting your doc-string in the description should do the trick. Check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for more info.